# Read a file post in httpServletRequest

Tags: servlets, file-upload

I have a html page like this :

```
<FORM METHOD="POST" ACTION="http://localhost:8080/Appli/page/public/envoiPjExterne.seam"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="file" size="70" name="file" /><br />     
     <INPUT type="submit" value="Submit">
</FORM>
```

and an servlet like this :

```
protected void doPost(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

DiskFileUpload upload = new DiskFileUpload();
upload.setSizeMax(10000000);// 10 Mo
List items;
try {
        items = upload.parseRequest(request);
        Iterator itr = items.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext()) {
            FileItem item = (FileItem) itr.next();
        }
    } catch (FileUploadException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My list "items" is always empty !

Answer (score 0):

That can happen if you have some `Filter` in the request-response chain which already automatically parses `multipart/form-data` requests. As request bodies can be parsed only once (the client ain't going to resend the uploaded file multiple times), a second attempt to parse it will result in nothing.

The file extension in form's action URL `envoiPjExterne.seam` suggests that you're using [JSF/Seam](http://seamframework.org/). This often goes hand in hand with [RichFaces](http://jboss.org/richfaces) which indeed comes with a filter like that.

There are 2 ways to solve this problem:

- Do not submit to a JSF/Seam view. Map the servlet on an unique URL pattern which is not covered by JSF/Seam and let the form action point to that instead. E.g. `action="uploadServlet"`.
- Do not use a servlet to process the file upload. Use RichFaces' own `<rich:fileUpload>` component with a simple JSF backing bean.